# Circle/daisy layout (pinwheel) in Android?

Tags: android, graphics, layout, canvas, view

I want to create a circle layout. All of my views should be in the circle. Which layout do I have to prefer and how? The focus of the layout should be a clockwise circle.

Edit:

I can do this view and it is an update of my question, prompted by the comments to this question. Is there any example for doing that?

The screenshot is attached below.

[image http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e11f35e522.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e11f35e522.png)

Comment: What the heck is a circle layout?

Comment: I have an idea to make my layout circle. and rotate it to select the category of the data. what the heck in it?

Comment: I think he wants to make it up... However I'm not understanding what the advantage of a circular layout on an inevitably square screen is.
Or are you trying to rotate through views circling to the left/right of the screen? Like a carousel?

Comment: I got this Idea by the MSNBC App in Iphone Store. Please check that. If you have possible. I will post the Screenshot shortly.

Comment: I would call it daisy layout :)

Comment: @ognian: thanks for the Note. how to do that plz?

Comment: It's better be a custom View, instead of a Layout that contains another Views. How would you layout some arbitrary Views in a circle, if you were designing a Layout? They would overlap near the center; I'll only work good with such flower-like Views

Comment: @ognian: I have no idea about this. So post some code or articles to know about more? Lagging in Logic.

Comment: @Praveen : did u get any idea..onit?

Comment: @Shubh: Not Yet. I did not get any Idea.

Comment: @Praveen: U solves this?

Answer (score 1):

For people who is coming to this question now  I recently had to implement this circle layout and after a lot of searching I decide that a relative layout that draws a petal shaped buttons will not give me the effect I needed so I followed those steps

you can see if you tested the nbc app on iphone they are placing invisible buttons on the words and the circle is just an image with the button overlaid but I didn't like this solution .

So here's how I implemented it

1- asked for the flower with the words on it from the UI guy and told him that the colors must be solid no gradient what so ever and then asked him to send me the hexadecimal values of each color.

2- then I implemented a motion listener that checks the color of the pixel the user clicked on ACTION_UP event and launch the event corresponding with the category of that color .

3-I check the color by getting x & y from the listener and then get the color from the image bitmap

I'll post snippets of the code If anyone needs it but I don't have it on me now.