# Android: custom button shape

Tags: android, touch, draw

I'm trying to achieve a custom controller containing of various buttons in different shapes. I'm wondering how I can achieve this with Android.

The result should look similar like this, where every color is a different button.
[image]

I suppose I have to subclass `View` so please don't write that as an answer ;-) Please give some methodical steps what's needs to be implemented, like drawing, sensing touches, etc or maybe point me to some examples (if exist).

Thanks

Comment: Relative post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239528/circle-daisy-layout-pin-wheelin-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) explaining everything in detail and having links pointing to related topics.

Answer (score 1):

if you intend to draw this dynamically you would have to extend View and override onDraw, you can implement onTouchListeners, etc to detect when and where people are touching it.